# Is it normal for my 10 month old boy to lick my face

Tags: infant, behavior, activities

My 10 month old boy licks my face,especially my nose when i bring him close to my face.

He does this only to me. But i am concerned. i tried to distract him when he licks but he thinks of it as fun and repeatedly does that.Is this normal?

Comment: Was normal for our daughters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Genuinely, not an issue. Don't worry. He's having fun, he probably thinks that it's kissing or something. It's very normal for children to be more physically affectionate with their mother.

Comment: It sounds to me like a way to get a reaction out of her, not to show affection. Do you have any references to show this is normal behavior?

Comment: No, because searching is hard for that ;-). You're right, the comment is mostly anecdotal; I know many parents and children's workers and they say that at that age it's very normal for such things. And you're right, if there's a reaction that will certainly exacerbate the behaviour.

Comment: I can only second that. I always liked that, when my daughter did that, I thought it was fun, too. She is now a year old and does not do it any more.

Comment: At ten months normal is a very broad curve

Answer (score 2):

Babies for 1 lick EVERYTHING but yes it is normal because they do see it as a game and some see it as first forms of kisses. My 10monthbold thinks it's hilarious and will do it and I'll yell yuckyyyy and he smiles and laughs. He does it a few times a day when he is in my face.